# Tail Sum Formula: Expected Maximum

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, dice

**Tail Sum Formula** states that:

For $X$ with possible values $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots , n\}$,
$$\operatorname E(X) = \sum_{j=1}^n P(X \ge j)$$

> Suppose that 4 dice are rolled. Find the expected maximum $\operatorname E(M)$ of the
>   4 rolls.

$M$ has possible values $\{1, 2, \ldots, 6\}$ all consecutive. Thus, we can use the Tail Sum Formula.

\begin{align}
\operatorname E(M) & = \sum_{j=1}^{6}P(M \ge j) \\[10pt]
& = P(M \ge 1) + P(M \ge 2) + P(M \ge 3) + P(M \ge 4) + P(M \ge 5) + P(M \ge 6) \\[10pt]
& = \left(\frac 6 6 \right)^4 + \left(\frac 5 6 \right)^4 + \left(\frac 4 6 \right)^4 + \left(\frac 3 6 \right)^4 + \left(\frac 2 6 \right)^4 + \left(\frac 1 6 \right)^4 \\[10pt]
& = 1.755
\end{align}

But the expected minimum is also $1.755$!

**Edit 1:**

Let $X_i$ be the value obtained on roll $i$, $1 \le i \le 4$.

$P(M \ge j) = $ Probability that the maxium of these 4 rolls is $\ge$ j

$= 1 - P(M \lt j)$

$= 1 - P(M \le j-1)$ Probability that the maxium of these 4 rolls is $\le$ j

$= 1 - P(X_1 \le j - 1, X_2 \le j - 1, ..., X_6 \le j - 1)$

Since each roll is independent...

$= 1 - P(X_1 \le j - 1) P(X_2 \le j - 1) ... P(X_6 \le j - 1)$

$= 1-(\frac{j-1}{6})^4$

\begin{align}
\operatorname E(M) & = \sum_{j=1}^{6}P(M \ge j) \\[10pt]
& = P(M \ge 1) + P(M \ge 2) + P(M \ge 3) + P(M \ge 4) + P(M \ge 5) + P(M \ge 6) \\[10pt]
& = \left(1- (\frac 0 6)^4 \right) + \left(1- (\frac 1 6)^4 \right) + \left(1- (\frac 2 6)^4 \right) + \left(1- (\frac 3 6)^4 \right) + \left(1- (\frac 4 6)^4 \right) + \left(1- (\frac 5 6)^4 \right) \\[10pt]
& = 5.244598765
\end{align}

Comment: You're computing the expected minimum.  Look at the second term.  $(5/6)^4$ is the probability that each die shows at least $2.$  You want the probability that at all dice show at most $2$ and at least one shows $2$.

Comment: $\left(5 \cdot \dfrac 1 6 \right)^4$ is the probability that all four outcomes are $\ge 2;$ thus it is the probability that the minimum is $\ge 2,$ not that the maximum is $\ge 2. \qquad$

Comment: Hint: $$E(M) = \sum_{j=1}^{6}P(M \ge j)  =  \sum_{j=2}^{6}(1 - P(M < j))$$  I got $E[M] = \dfrac{6797}{1296} \approx 5.2446$ using [Julia](//julialang.org).

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks everyone! I think I got it. See Edit 1.

Comment: For verification: by simulation of a million 4-roll experiments, $E(Max) \approx 5.24,\,SD(Max)\approx0.96,$ and $E(Min) \approx 1.76,\, SD(Min) \approx 0.96.$